# How to use nativescript with angular2 and firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, nativescript

Could somebody point me to the sample how to use Angular 2 with NativeScript and Firebase backend.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this project for the [`nativescript-firebase`](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase) plugin for nativescript (iOS and android).

Additionally, here is a project walkthrough on the firebase [blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/getting-started-with-nativescript-and_53.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is an advanced seed project for Angular apps based on Minko Gechev's angular-seed that expands on all of its great features.

https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced

- Clone the Repo Install
- Android SDK

Installing Firebase
https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced/wiki/How-to-integrate-Firebase-across-all-platforms-(web-nativescript-desktop)